# How to setup Kibana (EFK stack) on Azure Kubernetes cluster using reverse proxy ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, nginx-ingress, efk

Firstly wants to thank you for an amazing article above.

I have a scenario I want to get some help with, So I have installed Elastic search, Filebeat and Kibana on AKS cluster. Now, since I am using Nginx Ingress controller to expose application on Reverse proxy load balancer which is hooked to a hostname say http://example.com

I am not able to expose kibana to outside. I get 404 error. I have tried to add serverbasepath variable in kibana deployment etc. but still get 404 error.

- name: SERVER_BASEPATH
  value: "/kibana"

Below is my setup:
1.Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: frontend-ui-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: home-micro-service
          servicePort: 3333
        path: /api-dev(/|$)(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: kibana-kibana
          servicePort: 5601
        path: /kibana(/|$)(.*)
```

2.Kibana - values.yaml

```
---
elasticsearchHosts: "http://elasticsearch-master:9200"

replicas: 1

# Extra environment variables to append to this nodeGroup
# This will be appended to the current 'env:' key. You can use any of the kubernetes env
# syntax here
extraEnvs:
#  - name: "NODE_OPTIONS"
#    value: "--max-old-space-size=1800"
#  - name: MY_ENVIRONMENT_VAR
#    value: the_value_goes_here

# Allows you to load environment variables from kubernetes secret or config map
envFrom: []
# - secretRef:
#     name: env-secret
# - configMapRef:
#     name: config-map

# A list of secrets and their paths to mount inside the pod
# This is useful for mounting certificates for security and for mounting
# the X-Pack license
secretMounts: []
#  - name: kibana-keystore
#    secretName: kibana-keystore
#    path: /usr/share/kibana/data/kibana.keystore
#    subPath: kibana.keystore # optional

image: "dockerRepo/docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana"
imageTag: "7.9.1"
imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"

# additionals labels
labels: {}

podAnnotations: {}
  # iam.amazonaws.com/role: es-cluster

resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "2Gi"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "2Gi"

protocol: http

serverHost: "0.0.0.0"

healthCheckPath: "/app/kibana"

# Allows you to add any config files in /usr/share/kibana/config/
# such as kibana.yml
kibanaConfig: {}
#   kibana.yml: |
#     key:
#       nestedkey: value

# If Pod Security Policy in use it may be required to specify security context as well as service account

podSecurityContext:
  fsGroup: 1000

securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop:
    - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1000

serviceAccount: ""

# This is the PriorityClass settings as defined in
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#priorityclass
priorityClassName: ""

httpPort: 5601

extraContainers: ""
# - name: dummy-init
#   image: busybox
#   command: ['echo', 'hey']

extraInitContainers: ""
# - name: dummy-init
#   image: busybox
#   command: ['echo', 'hey']

updateStrategy:
  type: "Recreate"

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  port: 5601
  nodePort: ""
  labels: {}
  annotations: {}
    # cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/openstack-internal-load-balancer: "true"
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/cce-load-balancer-internal-vpc: "true"
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
    # 0.0.0.0/0

ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  path: /
  hosts:
    - chart-example.local
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

readinessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 3
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 5

imagePullSecrets: []
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []
affinity: {}

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

lifecycle: {}
  # preStop:
  #   exec:
  #     command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
  # postStart:
  #   exec:
  #     command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]

# Deprecated - use only with versions < 6.6
elasticsearchURL: "" # "http://elasticsearch-master:9200"
```

Comment: Could you give me a link to this article? As far as I know if you want to use `server.basePath` then additionally you have to set `server.rewriteBasePath: true`. Could you try to change that as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54416449/11977760)?

Answer (score 0):

Your image version is 7.9.1, as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/settings.html)

> server.rewriteBasePath:
>
> Specifies whether Kibana should rewrite requests that are prefixed with server.basePath or require that they are rewritten by your reverse proxy. In Kibana 6.3 and earlier, the default is false. **In Kibana 7.x, the setting is deprecated**. In Kibana 8.0 and later, the default is true. Default: deprecated

As far as I know if you want to use `server.basePath` then additionally you have to set `server.rewriteBasePath: true`

Try to add the following to the Kibana config:

```
server.basePath: "/kibana"
server.rewriteBasePath: true
```

Additionally, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/issues/2118#issuecomment-702215944) by @anyasabo

> You would need to override the path for the readiness probe in the podtemplate of your kibana resource. Currently it is hardcoded to /login

---

If that won't work I would suggest to check if ingress is configured properly.

For example create simple ingress with just `/` path to kibana and check if it works.

---

Additional resources:

- [Kibana deployed to kubernetes cluster returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413885/kibana-deployed-to-kubernetes-cluster-returns-404)